# How can I get those exact distinct (chinese) look of the eyes?

Tags: gimp, images, image-quality, image-editing

I have a low resolution image of a person and I was able to manage to increase the resolution of the image by manually improving all the features. But I'm now stuck on how to get that exact look on the face. How do I get exactly those Chinese eyes? As you can see the original image has a distinct look and I'm certain it is possible to get that distinct look in high definition. I just can't manage to get those eyes... I don't know what I am missing.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I was able to improve it this time... but not too sure if this is correct.

[image]

Comment: To me, they look like stylised south east asian eyes, monolid or at least partially rounded inner canthus. Everybody else's attempts look too 'european', even with the lower angle adjustment.

Comment: it looks like the OP is free-handing the eyes, and also making up details because they think "eyes look like that." This is fine if they want to draw *any* eyes but they seem to want *these* eyes. if they were to trace them instead on a layer above the original image...

Comment: yes i tried tracing them on a new layer above it, i updated what i was able to come up with.

Answer (score -2):

Not an artist but I think the "look" comes from the almost straight (if not curved up) lower eyelid:

[image]